# Why does my zookeeper cluster not doing leader election?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I have startup 3 zookeeper nodes ,but I find they have not done master election operation always ,the /servers/leader node does not exist.so how do I tell them the strategy to do election ?

Comment: Can you please post your code/config? That would make it easier to help. Thanks.